# FB chat worked fine with XMPP, but issue with getting friends list... Android

Tags: android, facebook, list, chat

FB chat wrkd fine 4 me. I used asmack-15-issue.jar and hostname:chat.facebook.com, port: 5222 and service name: chat.facebook.com. But the issue is with email id's. when iam extracting the friends chat list and dispalying in a listview, their email id's are being dispalyed in some unkown format ex: -1233708987@chat.facebook.com but not their exact id's.
Anyone, please help me in resolving dis issue....

Thanks,
Hareen

Comment: Hi Hareen  I am searching for the facebook chat in android .Can u provide me the sample code

Comment: Hi Pinki, FB chat is no where different from gtalk chat, for which u can find the source code at http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/

Comment: ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
42                 new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service); //Here for host u give as chat.facebook.com, port = 5222 and service = chat.facebook.com. And also just add a line.  SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0); Try this, if u are still unable to get it work. Let me know... Thanks, Hareen

Comment: hi Hareen .. i am facing the problem to connect facebook chat in my application..i also mention my problem related to this in S.O. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532328/problems-with-connecting-to-facebook-xmmp-md5-digest  this is the link ..please give me solution how i am connected with XMPP..

Comment: @Hareen how you could get the online friends and chatting,i also connected using xmpp facebook chat,how to get the friends list and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ll solve the problem

```
// Get the user's roster
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();

// Print the number of contacts
for(RosterEntry entry:roster.getEntries()){
    System.out.println(entry.getName());
}
```

Comment: How can i get only online friends,using this code its returning all my fb friends lists