# How to get the API key & session key & session secret key  for FB Chat on Android

Tags: android, facebook-chat, asmack

I am trying to build a chat app for Facebook in android. I am using  the **X-Facebook Platform** authentication method.

How can I get the *api key* & *session key & session secretkey*. I read in a tutorial that we get it from the FB by signing in as developer & by creating a new app. Can someone please explain it detail?

I have followed this tutorial [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532328/problems-with-connecting-to-facebook-xmmp-md5-digest]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532328/problems-with-connecting-to-facebook-xmmp-md5-digest)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532328/problems-with-connecting-to-facebook-xmmp-md5-digest)

Comment: @AndroidCoader Iam new to here.So don't know  how to increse it.Can you help me?

Comment: @userSeven7s i don't know how to accept it.Can you please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging into Facebook XMPP with encrypted access token format ](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7738616/logging-into-facebook-xmpp-with-encrypted-access-token-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was worked on this FB Xmpp client. i used smack library for this, it's working for me along with this u have to use [SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.java:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317329/xmpp-with-java-asmack-library-supporting-x-facebook-platform/5843759#5843759) look at my Question here [How to create XMPP chat client for facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook) . it solve your problem..