# Facebook XMPP, API and session key failing

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp

I am trying to create the desired Facebook keys for my XMPP application using the asmack library. I found a question on SO, that suggested using doing [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532328/problems-with-connecting-to-facebook-xmmp-md5-digest)

In addition, the post also stated you needed to create a HTTPget request to this [url:](https://api.facebook.com/method/auth.promoteSession?access_token=yourAccessToken)

I make a HttpGet request using Async (Standard stuff and it all works, so there's no need to show you that). But, the response is just an endless right arrow shift. Do I need to include the users username and pass too, I didn't submit anything, but the SO answer clearly states it'a HttpGET not a HttpPost and when I visit the above link in a browser it's just a plain XML document with the error code 190, I assume that's an internal Facebook error as there's not TCP/HTTP error of that number.

I can include the code if you want, it's just really messy.

Thanks and here's the response for references.

```
07-23 07:09:33.305: E/FBAPIRESULT(7404): <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
07-23 07:09:33.315: E/FBAPIRESULT(7404): <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404): java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404):     at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:70)
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:824)
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:267)
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
07-23 07:09:33.686: W/System.err(7404): Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
07-23 07:09:33.696: W/System.err(7404):     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
07-23 07:09:33.696: W/System.err(7404):     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
07-23 07:09:33.696: W/System.err(7404):     at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
07-23 07:09:33.696: W/System.err(7404):     ... 5 more
07-23 07:09:34.616: W/System.err(7404): SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM: 
07-23 07:09:34.616: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:259)
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:207)
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404):     at com.gta5news.qwuik.Main$1.run(Main.java:266)
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404): SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM: 
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:259)
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:207)
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404):     at com.gta5news.qwuik.Main$1.run(Main.java:266)
07-23 07:09:34.626: W/System.err(7404):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Line 266 is just where I log in, so it will throw some errors as the values are not accurate.

Comment: I am facing this issue...How u solved??...can you help?

Comment: Which android version you are using?